# Node.js error : failed to initialize context

Tags: node.js, npm

I just installed Node.js from Visual Studio installation.

When I tried to call `node` on the command prompt, I got this error. I also got this when I tried to do `npm init` and `npm install`

[image: command prompt error]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem on my Windows 10 64-bit computer. From looking at Programs and Features, I saw that I had Node.js and Node.js Chakra installed. I uninstalled Node.js and then downloaded and installed again it from https://nodejs.org/en/download/.

This, however, did not fix the problem. So I uninstalled Node.js Chakra; and when I opened a new command prompt, node and npm were working.

However, I'm not sure if I needed to uninstall and reinstall Node.js or if I only needed to uninstall Chakra. I probably should have uninstalled Chakra first and node and npm might have worked after that.

Comment: this seems so far the most helpful answer. I did reinstall Node (both from Node.js itself and the ChakraCore distribution), and the problem resolved